# File createNewFile() Fails If-Statement When File length() Does Not

Tags: java, file, java-11, filewriter, export-csv

## What are the details of your problem?

Why does the If-Statement of `file.createNewFile()` not seem to trigger?

The file does create and does do `fileWriter.append()` after this if-statement.
If I create a `if (!file.createNewFile())` this triggers every time after.
The file does append on the `file.length()==0`.

Why does the file create and append fine but the if block doesn't work?

## What did you try and what were you expecting?

I've tried to whittle down my problem to the smallest snippet for illustration.
If instead I should be making the smallest readily run program, let me know and I will update this.

```java
            String exportFilePath = "some/where/to/export/file.csv";
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(exportFilePath, true);
            File file = new File(exportFilePath);
            if (file.createNewFile()) {
                System.out.println("Created File:\t" + file);

                // This Does Not Work 
                fileWriter.append(String.join(",", headers))
                        .append("\n")
                        .close();
            }
            if (file.length()==0)

                // This Does Work 
                fileWriter.append(String.join(",", headers))
                        .append("\n")
                        .close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with me not understanding that `File file = new File(exportFilePath);` creates the file on at least the latest `Java 11.0.16+11`.

I was able to remove all of that and now the code works as this:

```
        File file = new File(exportFilePath);
        if (file.length() == 0) fileWriter.append(String.join(",", headers)).append("\n");
        fileWriter.append(String.join(",", currentLine)).append("\n").close();
```

Comment: `new File` does **not** create a file in the file system if it does not exist.  A `File` is simply a representation of a path name. And [per the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#length()) the length of a non-existent file is zero.